# link boost libs to qt with msvc

Tags: c++, qt, boost, msvc12

I have installed `qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64_opengl-5.4.0.exe` and compiled `boost_1_58_0.zip` with this command: `b2 toolset=msvc --build-type=complete stage`. It works fine with Visual Studio, but when I try use it with Qt I get this error:

> :-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib'

Here is my .pro file:

> TEMPLATE = app
>
> QT += qml quick widgets
>
> SOURCES += main.cpp \
>       testclass.cpp
>
> RESOURCES += qml.qrc
>
> INCLUDEPATH += C:\boost
>
> LIBS           += "-LC:\boost\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib"
>
> #Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
>   QML_IMPORT_PATH =
>
> # Default rules for deployment.
>   include(deployment.pri)
>
> HEADERS += \
>       testclass.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the LIBS variable use just "-L" for correct library path (-L). You made a mix, specifying a file (lowercase l) while libs directory is missing.

You do not need to specify the library, boost has pragmas for that.

Comment: can you write what exactly you mean?

Comment: -L flag specifies a directory where to look for .lib files. -l (lowercse) specifies a library to look for. The latter is not required with boost. Boost libraries have (in include files) some #pragma that tell th ompiler which .lib they require. So with your -L specify just a path, not a file/library

Comment: I don't know what happen but your solution work sometime and when i close qt IDE and reopen that it don't work any more